# ServiceBus Processor - Dont concurrently process messages for the same session

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I want to process sessions concurrently. However, within each session, I want to process only one message at a time.

```
   ServiceBusProcessorClient processorClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
            .fullyQualifiedNamespace(InsightsServiceSBEndPoint)
            .sessionProcessor()
            .queueName(SuccesQueue)
            .maxConcurrentSessions(5)
            .maxConcurrentCalls(5)
```

With the above setting, the processor processes multiple sessions concurrently as intended. But say if I send 3 messages for session id#1, I see all the 3 messages being processed concurrently. I want these 3 messages to be processed one after the other (otherwise there is no benefit of using sessions)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 important processor configurations that impact session based processing.

1. `MaxConcurrentSessions` - the maximum number of sessions that can be processed concurrently by a function.
2. `MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession` - the maximum number of concurrent calls to the function per session. Thus the total number of concurrent calls will be equal to MaxConcurrentSessions X MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession.

The `maxConcurrentCalls` is not for sessions processing but for non sessions enabled entities. To achieve what you need, the code would be

```
   .sessionProcessor()
   .queueName(SuccesQueue)
   .maxConcurrentSessions(5)
   .maxConcurrentCallsPerSession(1) // the default should be 1 but depends on the SDK
```

Comment: With `.maxConcurrentSessions(5).maxConcurrentCalls(1)` it does not process sessions concurrently. Messages from only one session are processed at any given time. I want the sessions to be processed concurrently, but one after other within each session

Comment: I’ve confused maxConcurrentCalls with MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession. Will update the answer.

Comment: I see `maxConcurrentCallsPerSession` available for dotnet sdk, but not in java sdk. Strange.

Comment: Looks like it is an open item: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/33232

Comment: That's why I added the note about SDK. In .NET SDK it's found and working as you'd expect it.